# How to join two tables having one will be limit in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, report

I am having a hard time configuring on how to join two tables, which the second one should be limit.

Below are the samples of my table.

This is employee table:

```
id EmpID Lastname Firstname Department
1  4     Joe      Dylan     Admin      
2  5     Black    Teddy     Admin
```

This is the attendance table:

```
EmpID  Date      TimeIn  TimeOut
4      2015-1-1  07:45   17:15
4      2015-1-2  08:15   15:00
4      2015-1-3  08:05   17:00
5      2015-1-1  08:00   16:00
5      2015-1-2  09:00   18:00
```

I want to combine the two tables by EmpID and show only one employee per page.

This is a sample of my expected result:

```
EmpID: 4  
Dept: Admin
Name: Joe, Dylan
Date    TimeIn    TimeOut
2015-1-1  07:45   17:15
2015-1-2  08:15   15:00
2015-1-3  08:05   17:00
```

Comment: Have you tried something? It looks like a simple join where you just do a `WHERE` condition on the `EmpID`

Comment: Post your attempts. What you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried this query: select * from table1, table2 where table1.date between Date(from) and Date(to) and table1.ID = table2.ID order by table2.ID ASC.

Comment: That's not how it works, Google mysql JOIN

Comment: just add a condition empid=4 in your where clause.

Comment: That's just the sample but the actual have 800 IDs.

Comment: select * from table1, table2 where table1.date between Date(from) and Date(to) and table1.ID = table2.ID and table1.empid = 4  order by table2.ID ASC

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? what is the role of limit here?

Comment: I only need to show one employee per page with their attendance for the whole date duration that the HR rep had selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join and put where condition as:

```
$id=4;
$query="select employee.* ,attendance.* from (select * from employee where EmpID='".$id."') employee inner join attendance on employee.EmpID=attendance.EmpID";
```

Comment: I need to limit table1 so that i can only show one employee per page.

Comment: I will try to rephrase what my desired output. I want to show records of attendance per 1 record of employee per page.

Comment: Check the changed query

Comment: does a and b the same as table1 and table2?

Comment: Yes you can also use a & b as table name (Please check i have changed the query)

Comment: I will try your solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: thanks i tried your code several times with different condition and it still works. Now I am only adding the pagination per page.

Comment: great.......enjoy php.

Comment: Can you help to my next problem that just arises just now in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730563/having-trouble-with-pagination-in-php.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * from employee 
LEFT JOIN attendance on attendance.EmpID=employee.EmpID
```

This will all attendance result of all employee; however if you want per page one employee record then trigger same query with PAgination;

```
SELECT * from employee 
LEFT JOIN attendance on attendance.EmpID=employee.EmpID
WHERE employee.EmpID=per_page_emp_id
```

As per you comment that you need date requirement too then...

```
SELECT * from employee 
LEFT JOIN attendance on attendance.EmpID=employee.EmpID
WHERE employee.EmpID=per_page_emp_id AND (
 attendance.date BETWEEN state 2015-1-1 AND 2015-1-1
```

Comment: I want to limit the employee table by 1 so that it will conform to my previous/next button in my page.

Comment: I wish you know pagination concept; or you can pass EmpID anyway if your convenience.

Comment: I also have date duration which will show employees that are present on that date selected by the HR.

Comment: Please make your question with full requirements and details

Comment: ok, sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I will try your solution but can it comply to the requirements of pagination?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90295/discussion-between-chintan7027-and-rayden-black).