# How to add pagination in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I already solve my query issues now the pagination that I implement together with won't work even if the syntax may look like it will work. i already tried every suggestion of every programmers community but its not doing any changes to the result. Kindly help me because this is the last requirement to me to complete the project. Here is the code:

```
$fromDate = "2015-01-01";
$toDate = "2015-01-30";
$dept = "PACKING";
$user = "root";
$pass = "admin";
$host = "localhost";
$db = "tempdb";

try{
    $cxn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
    $cxn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $cxn->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Unable to connect to server" . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
try{
    if(isset($_POST['id'])  &&
    isset($_POST['empid'])  &&
    isset($_POST['employee'])   &&
    isset($_POST['department']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $empid = $_POST['empid'];
        $employee = $_POST['employee'];
        $department = $_POST['department'];
        if($_POST['submit']==0)
        {
            $query = $cxn->prepare("SELECT emptb.*, tempstore.* FROM (SELECT * FROM 
emptb WHERE id < '".$id."' Department = :dept ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)emptb  
inner join tempstore 
on emptb.EmpID = tempstore.EmpID WHERE tempstore.ValidDate BETWEEN
DATE(:fromDate) AND DATE(:toDate)");
            $query->bindParam(':fromDate',$fromDate);
            $query->bindParam(':toDate',$toDate);
            $query->bindParam(':dept',$dept);
            $query->execute();
            $s = $query->fetch();
            extract($s);
            $id = $id;
            $empid = $EmpID;
            $employee = $Lastname . ", " . $Firstname;
            $department = $Department;
        }
        elseif($_POST['submit']==1)
        {
            $query = $cxn->prepare("SELECT emptb.*, tempstore.* FROM (SELECT * FROM 
emptb WHERE id > '".$id."' Department = :dept ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)emptb
inner join tempstore 
on emptb.EmpID = tempstore.EmpID WHERE tempstore.ValidDate BETWEEN
DATE(:fromDate) AND DATE(:toDate)");
            $query->bindParam(':fromDate',$fromDate);
            $query->bindParam(':toDate',$toDate);
            $query->bindParam(':dept',$dept);
        $query->execute();
        $s = $query->fetch();
        extract($s);
        $id = $id;
        $empid = $EmpID;
        $employee = $Lastname . ", " . $Firstname;
        $department = $Department;
    }
}
else
{
    $query = $cxn->prepare("SELECT emptb.*, tempstore.* FROM (SELECT * FROM
emptb WHERE Department = :dept ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)emptb inner join
tempstore 
on emptb.EmpID = tempstore.EmpID WHERE tempstore.ValidDate BETWEEN
DATE(:fromDate) AND DATE(:toDate)");
    $query->bindParam(':fromDate',$fromDate);
    $query->bindParam(':toDate',$toDate);
    $query->bindParam(':dept',$dept);
    $query->execute();
    $s = $query->fetch();
    extract($s);
    $id = $id;
    $empid = $EmpID;
    $employee = $Lastname . ", " . $Firstname;
    $department = $Department;
}   
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Unable to execute query " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
echo "<form action='' method='post'><pre>
    ID<input type='text' readonly='readonly' value='$empid'>
    Employee<input type='text' readonly='readonly' value='$employee'>
    Department<input type='text' readonly='readonly' value='$department'>
    <button name='submit' value='0'>PREVIOUS</button> <button name='submit' 
value='1'>NEXT</button></pre></form>";

echo "<table><tr><th>Date</th><th>TimeIn</th><th>LunchOut</th>  
<th>LunchIn</th><th>Timeout</th></tr>";
while($r = $query->fetch())
{
extract($r);
if($TimeIn=="00:00:00"){
    $TimeIn="";
}
else{
    $TimeIn= date("g:i",strtotime($TimeIn)) . " " . "AM";
}

if($LunchOut=="00:00:00"){
    $LunchOut="";
}
else{
    $LunchOut= date("g:i",strtotime($LunchOut)) . " " . "nn";
}

if($LunchIn=="00:00:00"){
    $LunchIn="";
}
else{
    $LunchIn=date("g:i",strtotime($LunchIn)) . " " . "PM";
}

if($TimeOut=="00:00:00"){
    $TimeOut="";
}
else{
    $TimeOut= date("g:i",strtotime($TimeOut)) . " " . "PM";
}
echo "<tr>
    <td>$ValidDate</td>\n
    <td>$TimeIn</td>\n
    <td>$LunchOut</td>\n
    <td>$LunchIn</td>\n
    <td>$TimeOut</td>\n</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: best to limit what you show, and not present it as "do it for me"

Comment: Errors? "Do it, test it, and give me" is not a question.

Comment: sometimes others want to check the whole code because the errors are not on the posted code but somewhere in the whole code. I am just following the advice of others.

Comment: That's the problem it doesn't echo any errors even on query.

Comment: we appreciate that. But you aren't even referring to any errors, just a dump of code. so ... aren't you really just saying, "hey go figure it out for me"

Comment: ahhh, that is why I am asking for help because there's no errors but it doesn't work. Kindly help me inspect the code for logic errors.

Comment: ok, I will spend the next 30 minutes trying to figure out what might be a logic error, harnessing my innate powers as a psychic. I will keep you posted http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first count the number of rows in your present query:

```
$numrows = $s->rowCount();
```

and need to place a vaiable for results per page say $resultsPerPage:

```
$resultsPerPage=10;
```

Then the page you are currenty in:

```
$offset=$_REQUEST['offset'];
```

Then you need to run the below code :

```
    $limit=$resultsPerPage;
    $PHP_SELF=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if($numrows >= 1) { 
           // determine if offset has been passed to script, or if offset has been tampered with.
            if (empty($offset) || ($offset < 0) || ($offset > $numrows)) {
                $offset=0;
            }
            // Determine if a "PREV" link is necessary - if so, add it to the links array
            if (($offset > 0) && ($offset <= $numrows)) { 
                $prevoffset = $offset - $limit;
                $link_array[] = "<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?offset=$prevoffset" . $addOn . "\">Prev</a> &nbsp; \n";
            }

            // Determine the total number of pages needing links
            $pages=intval($numrows/$limit);
            // $pages variable now contains integer number of pages needed, unless there is a remainder from division
            if ($numrows % $limit) {
                // There is a remainder, so add one page
                $pages++;
            }
        /*
            for ($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) { // loop thru
                $newoffset=$limit*($i-1);
                if ((intval($offset/$limit)) == (intval($i-1))) 
                {   $link_array[] = "[$i] &nbsp; \n"; }
                else {  
                    $link_array[] = "<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?offset=$newoffset" . $addOn . "\">$i</a> &nbsp; \n"; 
                }
            }
            */

        $start_page=intval($offset/$limit)-4;
        $end_page=intval($offset/$limit)+5;

        if($start_page<=0){
        $start_page=1;  

        }

        if($start_page<2){
        $end_page=10;  

        }

        if($end_page>$pages){
          $end_page=$pages;
        }



            for ($i=$start_page; $i<=$end_page; $i++) { // loop thru
                $newoffset=$limit*($i-1);

            if ((intval($offset/$limit)) == (intval($i-1))) 
                {   $link_array[] = "[$i] &nbsp; \n"; }
                else {  
                $link_array[] = "<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?offset=$newoffset" . $addOn . "\">$i</a> &nbsp; \n"; 
                }
            }

            // Determine if this is the last page.
            if (!(($offset/$limit)==$pages) && $pages!=1) {
                $newoffset=$offset+$limit;
                // if not last page give NEXT link
                if((($numrows - $offset) > $limit) && ($pages !=1) && ($offset < $numrows)){
                    $link_array[] = "<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?offset=$newoffset" . $addOn . "\">Next</a><br>\n";
                }
            }
        }else{
            ; // redirect to error page
        }

if ($resultsPerPage > 0  && count($link_array) > 1)
{   echo "Page: ";
    array_walk($link_array, 'printArray'); 
}
```

Comment: Can I use rowcount() in PDO mysql?

Comment: do i need to reconstruct my code or just add your solution.

Comment: I think you  try to make a function for pagination and then try to use